# Instagram basic display App Review was rejected due to:

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get approval by instagram for the following permissions:

- instagram_graph_user_profile
- instagram_graph_user_media

I have submitted a **VERY** detailed video showing the entire flow from on boarding to using the above apis.

I also added the following explanation on why I need these permissions:

> Dear review team,
> We are excited to introduce WatchMe, a Wear OS app that enhances user experiences by integrating seamlessly with Google Photos, Instagram, and AI technology to create personalized watch faces.
>
> Key Features:
> Google Photos & Instagram Sync
> AI-Powered Designs
> Dynamic Refresh
> Customizable Themes
> Privacy-Focused Approach
> Intuitive Interface
> Additional Information:
>
> Direct Integration with Google Photos & Instagram
> Cutting-Edge AI for Watch Face Designs
> Dynamic Refresh Settings
> Strong Commitment to User Privacy
> Active Global Community
> We kindly request approval for the Instagram Graph User Media permission to improve the Instagram integration within WatchMe, offering users a seamless experience.
>
> Thank you for considering WatchMe. We look forward to enhancing the Wear OS experience for users worldwide.

And ofcourse added test users for **both google and instagram**.

Their response was:

App rejected - Missing Instagram Basic Display integration
Developer Policy 1.9 - Build a quality product
We weren't able to verify the use case outlined in your notes and screencast when we logged into your app.
To resolve this issue, please consider the following recommendations:

1. Check that your app is fully developed and has correctly integrated the requested permission before resubmitting for review.
2. Provide valid test credentials to access your app in a test environment/development mode. Development mode allows your app to access permissions with limited test data for complete review.
3. If your app is in live mode, create a test app for your live app to create an App Review submission.
4. Provide a valid test URL in your submission notes. This will enable us to access the testing environment of your app.
   For more information, visit our App Review Submission and Comon Mistakes Guide.
   **Your submission is missing notes for this permission**.

needless to say my app is fully developed.
regrading the submission notes, I have no idea what they are and what they need to include as they are completely missing from the docs.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!